# Vuex Store getter function not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, store, getter

This is my getters in the vuex store:

```
  const getters= {
    getUser: (state:any) =>  {return state.user}
  };
```

In my view I do:

```
<script lang="ts">
  ...
  import {createNamespacedHelpers} from 'vuex'
  const {mapMutations, mapGetters} = createNamespacedHelpers('user');

  export default Vue.extend({

    computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'getUser'
      ])
    },

    methods: {
      ...mapMutations([
        'change'
      ]),
      login() {
        this.change(email); //This is a function in the mutations. And this is working
        this.loggedin = this.getUser(); // Here it says error

      }
    }
  });
```

I get the error:

`TypeError: this.getUser is not a function`. The call `this.change(email);` to the mutation function is working though.

Comment: ok somehow this works: `this.loggedin = this['getUser'];`

Comment: try `this.loggedin = this.getUser; ` it will also work, you are trying to invoke a `fn` initially

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`computed` properties are not `methods` so they don't get invoked. It behaves like `setters` and `getters`

`this.getUser` is a computed property, behaves more as a value itself. You trying to treat it as `method` when you put `()` after to make it invoke. Which is not possible as it's not a `fn` that's why that error shows up.

Refer this - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods.

`Vuex getters/states` get included in `computed` properties of vue `instances` as their work itself is to return a `value`. However `mutations/actions` get include inside `methods` properties as it's job is to `perform` an operation example - making `async` request and update a `state`